# Dropping multiple files to Safari changes the file counter to 0

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, drag-and-drop

I wanna handle file drop in a webpage. If a user drag multiple files, there is a red circle counter of file count in OsX.
It looks like this:

[image: dragged files in OsX]

When I drag them over Safari, the counter changes to 0:

[image]

Can I change this behaviour? to work the same way in safari?

Comment: Are the dropped files populated at `event.dataTransfer.files`?

Comment: Is requirement to display `.length` of `event.dataTransfer.files` at `dragover` event?

Comment: Still valid for safari in macOS Sierra 2 years later. I was unable to find a bug report on that for webkit

Comment: Bug filed here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=181081

Answer (score 1):

TLDR;
You cannot. I'm sorry.

More tests: It's on application (browser) level. When you drag to Safari any kind of files in any webapp with dropdown ability, even iCloud, you will have same result as you show. On Chrome you will have diferent results. Counter will show you last result. Ex. when you drag files directly from dictionary, you will got counter of two, but when you drag on safari and then move cursor on chrome you will got zero.

You must change Safari code to fix that ;)